# getting values from associative arrays in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm programming in php for years, but i have encountered a redicilous problem and have no idea why it has happened. I guess i'm missing something, but my brain has stopped working!
I have an ass. array and when i var_dump() it, it's like this:

```
 array
  0 => 
    array
      4 => string '12' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array
      2 => string '10' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array
      1 => string '9' (length=1)
```

I want to do something with those values like storing them in an array, (12, 10, 9), but I dont know how to retrieve it! I have tested foreach(), array_value(), but no result. No matter what i do, the var_dump() result is still the same!
by the way i'm using codeigniter framework, but logically it should have nothing to do with the framework
thanks guys

Comment: You seem to have array inside array: so urarray[0]['4'] will return 12, urarray[1]['2'] return 10 and urarray[2]['1'] return 9

Comment: Can you show us your attempts with `foreach` ?

Comment: You're programming for years, but you can't tell that this isn't an associative array?

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm suspecting PHP as in [Partial Hospitalisation Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_hospitalization), it would go some way to explain the reasoning behind the question. In which case likely *many* years.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `array_map`

```
$array = array(
        0 => array(4 => '12'),
        1 => array(2 => '10'),
        2 => array(1 => '9'));

$array = array_map("array_shift", $array);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string '12' (length=2)
  1 => string '10' (length=2)
  2 => string '9' (length=1)
```

Comment: fwiw, you  can pass 'array_shift' directly to `array_map`; you don't need to use the anonymous function in the middle

Answer (score 0):

You can access them like this:

```
$array[0][4]= '13'; 
$array[1][2]= '11'; 
$array[2][1]= '10';
```

var_dump($array); gives this result:

```
    array(3) { 
      [0]=> array(1) { 
         [4]=> string(2) "13" } 
      [1]=> array(1) { 
         [2]=> string(2) "11" } 
      [2]=> array(1) { 
         [1]=> string(2) "10" } 
    }
```

Comment: Not very useful if he doesn't know in advance what the keys are.

Comment: I think there is an assumption here that he does know what it looks like, though.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
for ($i = count($array) ; $i >= 0 ; $i--) {
    foreach($array[$1] as $k => $v) {
        echo $k . "=>".$v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to end up in an array, declare one, then iterate over your items.

```
$arr = new array();

foreach ($arrItem in $yourArray) {
  foreach ($innerArrItem in $arrItem) {
    array_push($arr, $innerArrItem);
  }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unknown depth, you can do something like this:

```
$output = array();
array_walk_recursive($input, function($value, $index, &$output) {
    $output[] = $value;
}, $output);
```